# How to suppress "Update Links" Alert with xlwings

Tags: python, excel

I am interfacing with Excel files in Python using the xlwings api. Some Excel files I am interacting with have old links which cause a prompt to appear when the file is opened asking if the user would like to update the links. This causes the code to hang indefinitely on the line that opened the book until this prompt is closed by a user. Is there a way to modify the settings of the Excel file so that this prompt will not appear or it will be automatically dismissed without opening the actual file?

I have tried using the xlwings method:

```
xlwings.App.display_alerts = False
```

to suppress the prompt, but as far as I can tell this can only be run for an instance of Excel after it has been opened. There are some Excel api's that do not require a file to be open in order to read data like xlrd, but they are not very convenient for reading and copying large amounts of data (Multiple/Entire sheets of data).

The following code demonstrates the issue:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book(r'C:\Path\To\File\Filename')

print('Done')
```

On a regular Excel file the code proceeds through and prints "Done" without the need of user interference, but on an Excel file where the "update links" prompt comes up, it will not proceed to the print statement until the prompt is dismissed by a user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expanding on your first attempt -- you're not handling an App instance, rather you're trying to assign to the `xlwings.App` class.

However, it seems that the [`display_alerts` doesn't successfully suppress this alert](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/562) in `xlwings`, try this:

```
import xlwings as xw
app = xw.App(add_book=False)
app.display_alerts = False
wb = app.books.api.Open(fullpath, UpdateLinks=False)
```

Comment: I can see the logic of why this would work, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to solve the issue. I haven't thought of doing something like this, so I'll read into the api more to see if using a pre existing instance of Excel can be leveraged to solve the issue, Thanks!

Comment: This can be done through the `.api`, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Wow, Awesome! I'm not incredibly familiar with VBA or pywin32, so those last bits of code are a bit like magic to me. Does the .api give us access to the underlying pywin32 so we can operate with that, or is the code after that VBA? Additionally where does the "Open" function come from if I have not imported any other modules?

Comment: I'm not familiar with xlwings implementation, but it would seem that `.api` exposes the [Excel object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel/object-model). So the code after that is not VBA *per se*, but I would expect that many/most of the properties/methods will be exposed that way and implemented the same way you would via VBA.

Comment: `xw.Book(impl=xw._xlwindows.Book(xl=wb))` to get an xlwings workbook object. Xlwings is a wrapper around either pywin32 (Windows) or appscript (MacOSX) and since we have to use the implementation-specific COM API we have to import the private `_xlwindows`

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an implementation in xlwings to avoid update links messages now. I was able to bypass these alerts by adding the following

```
app.books.open(fname, update_links=False, read_only=True, ignore_read_only_recommended=True)
```

You can see these arguments available in the documentation [xlwings.Book.open(...)](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.main.Books.open)

Comment: This worked for me with xlsm workbook (macros). Thank you so much! The answer above using .api did not work with xlsm.

Answer (score 0):

I presently have 20+ source workbooks that I loop though to extract some rows of data.  It was intolerable to respond to the update links prompt of each opened workbook.  I tried the other solutions here but none worked for me.  After reviewing the cited xlwings docs, this is the solution that worked for me:

```
for fname in workbook_list:
    wb = xw.books.open(fname, update_links = False)
    # Extract some data...
    wb.close()
```

My environment is Win10Pro / Python 3.8.1 / pywin32 version: 303 / Excel 365 Subscription / xlwings 0.26.2